# Tooltip problems (fade out time)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

They there

I'm currently working on some tooltips using jQuery.

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
$(document).tooltip({
    content: function () {
        return $(this).prop('title');
    },
    show: null,
position: {
    my: "right top-25",
    at: "left+25 bottom"
  },
open: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.tooltip.animate({ top: ui.tooltip.position().top + 10 }, 100 );
  },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        ui.tooltip.hover(

        function () {
            $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(200, 1);
        },

        function () {
            $(this).fadeOut("200", function () {
                $(this).remove();
            })
        });
    }
});
});
});
})(jQuery);
```

I'm a beginner and got the code from somewhere else, tested more than one tho. But I'm having a problem, if you hover one link after another you will see that 'delay'. I'm talking about the slow fadeOut, I want them to fade out more fast, but I still should be able to reach the link on the tooltip.

Best solution would be to close the tooltip if another one opens.

Can you help me with that, always happy to learn something here :)

Edit:

It seems to work for me to add a delay instead of showing it directly:
show: {
    delay: 250
  }

Comment: The prompt to add code should not be dismissed by adding empty code blocks -1

Comment: And your codepen link is bad.... Update your question with relevant code and a good codepen link

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to add the relevant code. Linking to an off-site resource is ok to provide supplemental information or a demo, but you need to put the relevant information directly in your question. Also, your link gives a 404 (although that is a pretty cool 404 page).

Comment: sorry about the wrong link and killing the prompt, changed that. But still not possible to add a link [link](http://codepen.io/itsthalis/pen/ONdGVz)

Answer (score 0):

You can change `fadeOut` duration in line 24. Remember duration it's in milliseconds.

```
function () {
    $(this).fadeOut( HERE GOES DURATION , function () {
        $(this).remove();
    })
});
```

Comment: that seems not to work, maybe fadeOut the the wrong thing here. I always want to just show one tooltip at once, max